# Java EE 6 project deployment error in NetBeans 7.3.1

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, deployment, glassfish

First the little input of the structure of my project.

It's a web shop project that consists of three modules:

- EJB
- Remote desktop client
- Web client

There are total of six NetBeans projects involved:

1. The main EE project which contains all modules.
2. EJB module project
3. Web client module project
4. Remote client module project
5. Class-library project for EJB remote interfaces
6. Class-library project that contains classes that are "simplified" forms of entity classes, which are originally located in EJB module project. The reason why I decided to use those classes instead of original entity classes is because I had some problems with serializing/deserializing them when distributing to remote client application.

Now I shall describe how are those projects connected to each other (by refering to their list above):

- EJB project contains references to #5 and #6
- Web client project contains reference to #2
- Remote client project contains references to #2, #5 and #6
- EJB remote interfaces project contains reference to #6

So basicaly, all projects (except for the web module) contains reference to the project that contains simplified, or "encapsulated" forms of entity classes.

When I try to deploy this EE application (the main EE project) to GlassFish (v 4.0), I keep getting this error that classes which are defined in project #6 are not visible in project #5. There is this one "Product" class defined in project #6 that is used in remote interface in project #5. Durring code writting, I didn't get any error regarding this issue, as the references are placed correctly. Also, clean and build of the main EE project completes successfully, but when deploying, I still keep getting this same error:

```
package musicshop.entity.encapsulated does not exist
import musicshop.entity.encapsulated.Product;
```

Note: `musicshop.entity.encapsulated` is package from project #6 that contains that "Product" class. Also, this `import musicshop.entity.encapsulated.Product;` is line from that one remote interface from project #5.

Also, it is important to mention the fact that the whole thing worked fine until I undeployed application from GlassFish and tried to re-deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to say that I have managed to find the solution to this problem. It's not pretty, but it will serve the purpose until I find another way.

What I have discovered is that no more than one class library projects can be deployed on GlassFish. I used to have only one such project, the one that holds EJB remote interfaces. But when I created another class library project that would hold those simplified version of entity classes (I did it in order to keep all of those classes in one place and to import them wherever I need to use them. That way, if I wished to do some editing, I'd have to do it only once.).

So, what I had to do was to eliminate that additional class library project and to simply copy those classes everywhere where I need to use them. Now, I've scattered them accross other projects, which is going to make it hard now to maintain them, but it did solve the problem of deploying on server.

After doing so, I recall that I already tried once to do something simmilar - to create additional class library project that would contain something which would be imported wherever it's use is needed and I had the same errors when deploying application on GlassFish. Naturally, I solved that problem in the same manner as this one. So I'm left wondering why it isn't possible to deploy more than one class library project? Any ideas?